# Arduino: IR receiver, current draw and resistor

Tags: arduino, voltage, current, resistors, infrared

I was looking for an IR receiver example using an Arduino and I found this site (https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/IR-RemoteControl) which contains this image of how to wire the IR receiver...

[image: ir]

I don't understand why this circuit does **not** contain a resistor. Surely without a resistor this circuit would cause a large amount of current to flow, potentially damaging components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need a resistor in the VCC of an IC when you use it?  No.

[That IR-Receiver](https://arduino-info.wikispaces.com/file/view/IR-Receiver-AX-1838HS.pdf/264668680/IR-Receiver-AX-1838HS.pdf) is an integrated circuit that contains a lot more than just a photo diode.

So, the photo diode is integrated in a chip, and has all of the things needed to function properly.  It just happens to look like a simple, dumb photo transistor in form.